# How to catch errors in Powershell script invoked with Invoke-Expression?

Tags: powershell

I am calling one PS script from another using Invoke-Expression, but I am having trouble figuring out have to detect from the calling script the other script has failed. Actually I just want the calling script to stop in this case, and I was hoping that $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop" would do the trick.

Calling script:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"
$psCommand = ".\Work.ps1 -a -b " + $var
Invoke-Expression $psCommand

# More work
```

Work.ps1:

```
param
(
    [string]$a,
    [switch]$b = $false
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Do Stuff

If ($x -ne 0) 
{
    Write-Output ("Stuff failed")
    Exit 2
}
```

This does not work. The calling script does not stop after Work.ps1 exited with code 2. Do I need try-catch in the calling script? Or do I need to look at $error? (seems complicated)

Comment: `throw` instead of `exit`-ing

Comment: @Mathias: Thanks. That put me on the right track. Turns out that since I am using 
`$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"`, I can just do `Write-Error` instead of `Write-Output`. That stops the script as well.

Comment: Also, a benefit of that is you're not using Write-Output in your function (something I used to do in my early PowerShell days). When you look at the return from your function, if you've used Write-Output you'll get a string of text along with anything else you've wanted to return, all combined. It can be messy. If you think about how your usual PowerShell cmdlets are written, they don't often return text to the output stream, but instead return objects, nothing, a boolean, or an error and/or warning. Try and write functions like this and it'll serve you good in the future :)

Comment: @Robin: I actually do use Write-Output in several other places in the calling script. It writes various status messages that can be useful under certain circumstances. I'm not sure that I understand what I should do instead. The context is that the script is called from a Visual Studio build event (so a type of cmd-script). The Write-Output's get to be a part of the build log, which can be very useful.

Comment: Write-Output in a calling script is ok! Also inside a function if you're piping Write-Output to a log file; very useful for reviewing later. My apologies if this is what you were doing. If though you're looking to output information to the screen whilst executing the script, try `Write-Verbose` for informational messages and `Write-Debug` for debugging (e.g. checking if variables are what you expect, or if conditions are met, etc). To see these you can either write an advanced function that supports passing -Verbose or -Debug, or just set $DebugPreference or $VerbosePreference = 'Continue'.

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works because I use $ErrorActionPreference = "Stop". Otherwise I should throw:

```
param
(
    [string]$a,
    [switch]$b = $false
)
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Do Stuff

If ($x -ne 0) 
{
    Write-Error ("Stuff failed")
}
```

Comment: I am trying to, but SO will not let me do that yet. Newbie question: How do I upvote comments??